# Problem of removing outliers with the median

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

with this code I would like to delete the outliers of the dataframe "members" but when I run it nothing is deleted. Can you help me?

```
import pandas as pd 
members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")
mad = np.median(np.absolute(members["age"] - members["age"].median()))
members = members.drop(members.index[(members["age"] > members["age"].median()+3*mad)|(members["age"] < members["age"].median()- 3*mad)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) for avoid `NaN`s returned `np.absolute`:

```
mad = (members["age"] - members["age"].median()).abs().median()
print (mad)
7.0
```

Then second filtering should be change by invert mask by `~` instead `drop`:

```
members = members[~((members["age"] > members["age"].median()+3*mad)|
                    (members["age"] < members["age"].median()- 3*mad))]
```